# Sending data from android to arduino rx-tx USB

Tags: android, serial-port, usb, arduino-yun

I have an arduino that controls a car, I need a compass to control the car automatically, unfortunately we could net get a compass (not in stock, no online shopping availble in my country)

So the idea is this:

I will get a compass running on android and feed the data using the USB connection to send a hex data (as a serial connection)

I cann set tx/rx pins  on arduino, but i do not know the capabilites of android and whether i can actually manage this..

The idea is simple, get the data from the app and send it through the USB as a serial connection, no need for feed back or anything, just plug in the tx/rx wires coming from the phone into the arduino pins and start receiving.
How can I manipulate the USB in such a way? is it even possible?

Searching on google just returns unwanted results like connecting android to PC/ADB/external flash.. thise are not usedul at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I am sure you can do it I frequently use my phone with a [usb otg](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61TeaPKJFDL._SX569_.jpg) cable. Most new Android phones support usb otg but make sure to check first, not sure about iPhone. I suppose you can also just connect the rx and tx to a mini usb connector and plug that into the phone.  I use [Serial usb terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_usb_terminal&hl=en_ZA) to sent and receive data over the serial usb port. [Here](https://github.com/ksksue/Android-USB-Serial-Monitor-Lite) is a github app for serial communication you can just modify it to send the compass data.